# Gmail IMAP Authentication -- imaplib.authenticate takes exactly 3 args (4 given)

Tags: python, oauth, gmail

I'm trying to enable Gmail IMAP access from my web application.  Right now, users can grant access to the web application, successfully retrieving and storing the user's token and secret.  But, when I try to authenticate the IMAP connection for retrieving emails, it gives the following error:

```
TypeError: authenticate() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)
```

Here is the code (very simple):

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import imaplib

consumer = oauth.Consumer('token','secret')
token = oauth.Token('token','secret')

url = "https://mail.google.com/mail/b/username@gmail.com/imap/"
conn = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.googlemail.com')
conn.debug = 4
conn.authenticate(url,consumer,token)
```

I tried backing out a little bit to avoid the actual `authenticate` function, but to no avail:

```
imaplib.IMAP4_SSL.authenticate(conn,'XOAUTH',lambda x: oauth.build_xoauth_string(url,consumer,token))
```

This gives me similar output:

```
29:03.17 > CMIK6 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH
29:03.27 < CMIK5 BAD Too many arguments provided s68if10067716yhm.26
29:03.27 BAD response: Too many arguments provided s68if10067716yhm.26
```

I'm not sure what the problem could be.  Why would the `authenticate` function think there were 4 arguments?  Could the oauth strings be interpreted as multiple strings, i.e., not escaped properly?  They have slashes, underscores, plus signs, but no commas.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using the oauth2 imaplib wrapper? `import oauth2.clients.imap as imaplib`

Comment: `authenticate` is a method of `conn`, `self` is the first argument, I guess.

Comment: @Acorn that seems to have done the trick. I'm still playing around with it a bit, but for whatever reason it isn't throwing the same error.

Comment: @Acorn please list your comment as answer, and I'll give you the check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using oauth2 for IMAP, you need to use it in conjunction with `oauth2.clients.imap`, so:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import oauth2.clients.imap as imaplib

# the rest of your code as it was
```

You can see an example towards the bottom of this page: https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2

Answer (score 1):

The [authenticate](http://docs.python.org/library/imaplib.html) method only takes 2 arguments (3 when you include `self`). This [article](http://www.tylerlesmann.com/2009/apr/15/plain-imap-authentication-python/) explains how it works (the docs are not very helpful).

Your second attempt looks promising if you just provide the 2 args:

```
conn.authenticate('XOAUTH',lambda x: oauth.build_xoauth_string(url,consumer,token))
```

Hope that helps.

**UPDATE - IGNORE THE ABOVE**

Ignore all that, I think I know what the problem is. It looks like you are taking your example from the [python-oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) package. The example they give does not use Python's standard library `imaplib` but its own implementation.

You need to use python-oauth2 imap client:

```
import oauth2.clients.imap as imaplib
```

Here's the relevant section from thier example - which indeed requires 3 arguments as in your example:

```
# This is the only thing in the API for impaplib.IMAP4_SSL that has 
# changed. You now authenticate with the URL, consumer, and token.
conn.authenticate(url, consumer, token)
```